# SYSPBUFF OPTION

Tags: sas

I'm trying to write a macro code where i've used several keyword parameters and want one of those parameters to be able to read in multiple arguments/values.
I want to achieve something like this:

```
%MACRO TEST(CONDITION=, VVAR=, OUT_VAR=)/PARMBUFF;
%LET CNT = %sysfunc(countw(&syspbuff));
&OUT_VAR = .;

%DO I =1 %TO &CNT;
%IF &CONDITION=Y %THEN %DO;
&OUT_VAR=(SALARY+BUNUS)/COUNT(VALUES PASSED TO VVAR PARAMETER);
%END;
%END;
%MEND;

data person;
   input SALARY BONUS COND $;
   datalines;
100 50 Y
200 75 Y
300 0 N
;
%TEST(CONDITION=COND,VVAR=SALARY BONUS,OUT_VAR=AVG_SAL);
RUN;
```

Can anyone suggest how can I achieve that? I tired using the syspbuff options to read in the values for VVAR parameter, but it has all the values passed to all the parameters.
Thanks!

Comment: PARMBUFF is considered old school and that was a while ago. Do you really need this type of approach? There are several others, for example you can pass a space or pipe delimited list to any parameter, as long as its not comma delimited. And the usage doesn't make sense either because it's in the middle of a data step that won't work anyways. It may help to explain your intended objective with some more detail.

Comment: I need to be able to call a macro and perform some functions within the macro. For that I have some a set of parameters and want to be able to pass multiple values for one of the parameters. Ho can i achieve that then? Also, I do not want to create any macro vars(with the list of values delimited by some delimiter) inside my data step, I want to perform all calculations in the macro code.

Comment: See the example here: http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=mcrolref&docsetTarget=n1qvxz5u3uru7yn1nk7q64ohvwak.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en You can also pass a comma delimited list, but you need to mask the commas using macro quoting. Either way, this likely isn't the best approach.

Comment: what in your opinion could be the best approach then? I want to be able to achieve this : 1. Datastep to create the required data 2. Read that dataset and call in some macros , the macro parameters will be keyword parameters and should be able to read in multiple values. 3. In the macro body I need to be able to traverse through the different values supplied to each parameter differently, eg. I want to be able to read through the values for one parameter, perform some aggregation on it and create a new variable, similarly use other variables for different purposes.

Comment: What are you passing to the macro? Are you passing values that you want the macro code to interpret and use to generate a numeric literal to place into the generated data step code?  or do you want to pass the names of data step variables that can be used to generate data step code to manipulate values in the genrated data step?

Comment: I want to be able to pass variables from a dataset as macro arguments and then perform some calculations on them.

Comment: You cannot process the values of data step variables with macro code. You can use the names to generate SAS code that could process the data. You can manipulate the names to generate new names that you could use to generate code.

Comment: That is exactly that I intend to do. To be able to generate SAS Code that could process those variables' data, but, using macro code.

Comment: First write out the code you want to generate and make sure it works as pure SAS code. Then replace the variable parts that you want to vary with macro variables. Try it by setting the macro variables with %LET statements. Then make a macro that takes those macro variables as the parameters.

Comment: that is a great suggestion, i'll try doing that, thanks @Tom

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be confused about the timing of when macro code executes and when the code that the macro has generated is executed by SAS.  The macro processor does its work first and then passes the code onto SAS to interpret.  When SAS sees a complete data or proc step then it runs that step.

Here is my attempt to translate your post into something that could execute.  Not sure if it is what you are looking for.

First you have a macro that takes in three parameters. The first is some SAS expression that evaluates to a string. The middle is a variable list. And the last is a single variable name.  It uses these parameter values to generate SAS code that could be used inside of a data step to conditionally generate the mean of the variables in the list.

```
%MACRO TEST(CONDITION=, VVAR=, OUT_VAR=);
IF &CONDITION='Y' THEN DO;
&OUT_VAR=mean(of &vvar);
END;
else &out_var=.;
%MEND;
```

Now you will need to call that macro as part of a data step so that the code is generated in a place where SAS will understand it.  **Note** that when your data step is using inline data (CARDS/DATALINES) then the inline data most be the last thing in the data step.

```
data person;
   input SALARY BONUS COND $;
%TEST(CONDITION=COND,VVAR=SALARY BONUS,OUT_VAR=AVG_SAL);
datalines;
100 50 Y
200 75 Y
300 0 N
;
```

If you run it with the `MPRINT` option on you can see the SAS code that the macro has generated.  It is just the same as if you had typed that code directly into the data step instead of asking the macro to generate it for you.

```
615   data person;
616      input SALARY BONUS COND $;
617   %TEST(CONDITION=COND,VVAR=SALARY BONUS,OUT_VAR=AVG_SAL);
MPRINT(TEST):   IF COND='Y' THEN DO;
MPRINT(TEST):   AVG_SAL=mean(of SALARY BONUS);
MPRINT(TEST):   END;
MPRINT(TEST):   else AVG_SAL=.;
618   datalines;

NOTE: The data set WORK.PERSON has 3 observations and 4 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.06 seconds
      cpu time            0.03 seconds


622   ;
```

If you wanted to generate multiple new variables then just call it multiple times.  You could probably make the macro much more complicated by treating each input parameter as a delimited list of values and process the first set and then the second set etc.  But why?

If you want to know how many words appear in the value of a macro variable, like the VVAR parameter in the macro above, then you can use the `%sysfunc()` macro function to call the SAS function `countw()`.

```
%let cnt=%sysfunc(countw(&vvar));
```

You could then use the value of `&cnt` where you need it.  Say as the upper bound in a macro `%do` loop or as an integer constant in an expression in the generated SAS code.

Comment: HI Tom, this is what I intend to do :                                                       
 data person;
   input SALARY BONUS COND $;
   datalines;
100 50 Y
200 75 Y
300 0 N
;
RUN;
DATA PERSN_FNL;
 SET PERSON;
%TEST(CONDITION=COND,VVAR=SALARY BONUS,OUT_VAR=AVG_SAL);
RUN;
In the second parameter i want to be able to pass multiple variable names.

Comment: Then in the macro I want to first count these arguments passed to the second parameter and then find their average if the condition passed in the condition parameter is satisfied and assign the value to the var name passed in the third parameter of the macro call.

Comment: Sending the macro body code again:
 `OPTIONS MLOGIC SYMBOLGEN MPRINT;                                               
%MACRO TEST(CONDITION=, VVAR=, OUT_VAR=)/PARMBUFF;
%LET CNT = %sysfunc(countw(&syspbuff));
&OUT_VAR = .;

%DO I =1 %TO &CNT;
%IF &CONDITION=Y %THEN %DO;
&OUT_VAR=(SALARY+BUNUS)/COUNT(VALUES PASSED TO VVAR PARAMETER);
%END;
%END;
%MEND; `

Comment: Apologies, could not format the code in the comment.

Comment: Makes no sense. You could use the count of the number of names passed in &VVAR and use it as the denominator instead of using MEAN() function. The effect would be somewhat like treating missing values as if they were zeros.

Comment: So you plan to set parameter CONDITION to an upper case Y so that the %IF condition makes sense?

Comment: Not sure what your'e trying to ask. But tell me this :`
%MACRO TEST(CONDITION=, VVAR=, OUT_VAR=)/PARMBUFF;
%LET CNT = %sysfunc(countw(&syspbuff)); /* just want it to count VVAR arguements */
&OUT_VAR = .;
%DO I =1 %TO &CNT;
%IF &CONDITION='Y' %THEN %DO;
&OUT_VAR=(SALARY+BUNUS)/2 /*number of values passed to the VVAR parameter */;
%END;
%END;
%MEND;

data person;
   input SALARY BONUS COND $;
datalines;
100 50 Y
200 75 Y
300 0 N
;
run;
data person1;
set person;
%TEST(CONDITION=COND,VVAR=SALARY BONUS,OUT_VAR=AVG_SAL);
run;` is something like this doable in sas?

Comment: No. You can count number of words in VVAR.  `%sysfunc(countw(&vvar))`. If you use `%IF` to compare the string `COND` to the string `'Y'` it will always be false as it has nothing to do with any data step variable named `COND`.  The only way it could be true would be if called the macro with `condition='Y'`.

Comment: If you do a sum or average in a data step that only sums the row. I suspect that’s not what you want. And if it is an ARRAY is much easier.

Comment: Thanks Tom and Reeza for your suggestions, i'll update the code accordingly and see how I go.